# Firefox Addon Downloads.jsm

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, download-manager

I'm trying to use the [Downloads.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm) lib of Firefox (it's new in Firefox 23) in a jetpack addin.

```
var {Cu} = require("chrome"); //works fine
const {Downloads} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm"); //works fine
```

But executing either of these functions has no effect:

```
download = Downloads.createDownload({source: "http://cdn.sstatic.net", target: "/tmp/kaki.html"}); //download is an object but has no function "start"
Downloads.simpleDownload("http://cdn.sstatic.net","/tmp/kaki.html");
```

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm/Download

Do you have any idea, how to use these functions? I haven't found any examples on the web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API functions return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise), not the actual Download object.

In short, the following should work:

```
const {Downloads} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm", {});
var downloadPromise = Downloads.createDownload({source: "http://cdn.sstatic.net", target: "/tmp/kaki.html"})
downloadPromise.then(function success(d) {
  d.start();
});
```

Read up on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise), and to make dealing with them a lot more fun, also [Task.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Task.jsm)

The API did change quite a bit recently; what is documented is the current Aurora-25 or later API. The "old" API is documented within the [source](http://mzl.la/1cwWZ2N).

A more complete example with Firefox <25 support is available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nmaier/6220299).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I'm closer to the solution. I discovered that the `saver: "copy"` parameter has to be set. In this case the success function is called and `d` is really a `Download` object. But `d.start()` has still no effect.

Comment: The code I gave works for me verbatim in a chrome-privileged scratchpad (on OSX Nightly anyway), i.e. /tmp/kaki.html gets created with the correct contents. If you want more help, refine your question with more details and elaborate a bit.

Comment: Could you please share your example at [Add-on builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org)? I copied your code exactly and it doesn't work. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I really don't know what's wrong. I would be very grateful

Comment: Turns out the API changed quite a bit between <=24 (Beta) >=25 (Aurora). I posted a more complete example, incl. version detection here: https://gist.github.com/nmaier/6220299

Comment: Thank you very much, your help was indispensable! This code works perfectly